# DFS Replication Windows 2012 modification

Tags: powershell, replication, microsoft-distributed-file-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I use DFS replication on Windows 2012 R2. I create a group with option "replication group for data collection". My Folder "X" on my server A "Master" is replicated to the folder "X" on my server B "Slave".

I would like create an another group with My Folder "X" on my server B is replicated to the folder "X" on my server A. This group was not active, there is only if I need change my server A and change the ways replication from A to B by from B to A.
But it is refuse, because file X is used an another group.

So I think the best way is to change by PowerShell script and I would like get the replication group and change the server source and the server destination.

I found the command `Get-DFSR...` and `Set-DFSR...`, but I do not know how use them for makes that I would.

Answer (score 0):

Replication should already happen in both directions, unless you made one member [read-only](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/04/01/configuring-a-read-only-replicated-folder.aspx). In which case you should undo that modification.

As for using the DFSR PowerShell cmdlets: see [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2013/08/20/dfs-replication-in-windows-server-2012-r2-if-you-only-knew-the-power-of-the-dark-shell.aspx) from Ned Pyle (and the [fine manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296591.aspx), of course).